# Is there still a Gribov ambiguity when the Faddeev-Popov determinant is treated without ghosts?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, ghosts, functional-determinants

In [this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11659) (*Gribov Ambiguity* by Thitipat Sainapha) the setup leading to the equation $3.77$ seems to strongly depend on the treatment of the Faddeev-Popov determinants with ghosts. Indeed the partition function with the so-called "Gribov no pole condition" is defined by:
\begin{equation}
Z=\int \mathcal{D}A\int \mathcal{D}\bar{c}\int \mathcal{D}c\,\theta( 1-\sigma(0,A))\,e^{-S_{\text{YM}}[A,\bar{c},c]}
\end{equation}
Where $\sigma(k^2,A)$ is defined by $3.73$. But this very condition comes from the ghost propagator. What if we treat the Faddeev-Popov determinant like:
\begin{equation}
\det(-\partial_\mu D_\mu)=\det(-\bar{D}_\mu \bar{D}_\mu-E)\stackrel{!}{=}e^{\frac{1}{16\pi^2 g^2}\int d^4 x \text{Tr} \left( \frac{1}{2}E\cdot E+ \frac{1}{12} \bar{\Omega}_{\mu \nu} \cdot \bar{\Omega}_{\mu \nu} \right)}
\end{equation}
Where $\bar{D}=\partial+\frac{1}{2}f^{abc}A^b$, $\bar{\Omega}$ is the strength tensor associated with $\bar{D}$ and $E$ is a gauge term. I just followed the notation of [*Heat kernel expansion: user's manual*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138). Since the trace is negative due to the anti-symmetry of the structure constants and the matrix product "$\cdot$", it can be used inside the partition function at the beginning of the Faddeev-Popov method. Hence the theory is ghostless.

So my question is: is there still a Gribov ambiguity if we treat the Faddeev-Popov determinant as I did?